# Are messages sent to the consumer all at once if I set autoAck=true?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

There is a queue with 10000 messages in it. When I start a consumer (autoack=true), I can see from the `rabbitmq_management` that the number of messages quickly becomes zero. Does this mean that all the 10000 messages are on the consumer side? Where is it stored(I am using `Spring-AMQP`)? If the concurrency of my consumer configuration is 1 and processing a message takes a long time, is it possible to run out of memory(If count of messages is very large)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean; if you are using `basicConsume` directly, they will all be sent.

Spring has a slightly different interpretation; ack mode NONE means RabbitMQ autoAck (in `basicConsume`). AUTO means the container acks after the listener exits normally. MANUAL means user code is responsible for acking.

With Spring, ack mode NONE also depends on the container; with the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, only `prefetchCount` messages will be sent. To prevent OOM conditions, the internal queue blocks the delivery of additional messages until the listener processes the current message.

With the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` they will all be sent to the consumer, as with using `basicConsume` natively.

RabbitMQ `autoAck` is not generally recommended because it will cause potential message loss.

Comment: In the third paragraph, what does `only prefetchCount messages will be sent` mean? Beacuse I can see from the rabbitmq_management that the number of messages quickly becomes zero using `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and ack mode NONE.

Comment: From a Spring perspective, there is a `BlockingQueue` between the delivery thread and the listener thread; it is sized at the prefetch since 1.3.x (2013) - certainly back then, this stopped deliveries if the listener couldn't keep up. This avoided OOM errors for some users using NONE (autoAck). The default prefetch is 250. If you are not seeing that, then there could be some more buffering in the amqp-client code, which is out of our control. I know they made some threading changes there over the years, so that is entirely possible. As  I said, autoAck (NONE) is generally not a good idea.